# Do I need to run always findspark or once?

Tags: python, pyspark

My method of using pyspark is to always run the code below in jupyter. Is this method always necessary ?

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/opt/spark2.4')
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reduce the `findspark` dependency, you can just make sure you have these variables in your `.bashrc`

```
export SPARK_HOME='/opt/spark2.4'
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH:~/.local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

Change the directories according to your enviroment, and the spark version as well. Apart from that, `findspark` will have to be in your code for your python interpreter to find the spark directory

If you get it working, you can run `pip uninstall findspark`

### EDIT:

Pure python solution, add this code on top of your jupyter notebook (maybe in the first cell):

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/opt/continuum/anaconda/bin/python"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/opt/spark2.4"
os.environ["PYLIB"] = os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] + "/python/lib"
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ["PYLIB"] +"/py4j-0.9-src.zip")
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ["PYLIB"] +"/pyspark.zip")
```

Source : [Anaconda docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-scale/howto/spark-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using anaconda on Linux. is this still the same config?

Comment: I hope so! I can add another method to do it from the first block of your code, using just python

Comment: for your last edit edit I've to run it once on jupyter?

Comment: Yes. You will have to modify your directories if needed

Comment: (Edit) it worked I've added the first config you provide in bashrc then then run the second one on my jupyter notebook.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can call this only once, what this does is that it edits your bashrc file and set the environment variables there

```
findspark.init('/path/to/spark_home', edit_rc=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).